# Moving fetch "post" request to a separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

Can you please tell me if it is possible to make a "post" request in a separate file?
I made a folder with the file "api.js" and put the "get" requests there, I would like to know how to make the "post" requests (if possible).

For example, put this code into the "api.js" file.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();

    await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API + "account/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        Name: event.target.Name.value,
        Email: event.target.Email.value,
        Phone: event.target.Phone.value,
        Password: event.target.Password.value,
        PasswordConfirm: event.target.PasswordConfirm.value,
        RememberMe: RememberMe,
        UserRole: Roles,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          alert("Error");
        }
      ); 

    setRegister(true);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is possible, you just need to make sure your function which is doing the API call is returning the result. You then export the function from your new file.

Once that's done you can import it into the function where you want to use it and wait for your result there. I've made a small demo here which I hope helps:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-meitner-g5otf

An even neater way might be to use React Hooks and update a global context but for your needs the above should work.

Comment: When I made a request on your recommendation, the event was lost. The body writes that it is undefined. How to make it correctly?

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox to be a POST request. Hope that helps?